# VueJS emit to a function outside VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to emit something from within my VueJS component to a function which sits in the html page containing the component. Am I missing something, or is this not possible?

Within my component as a method:

```
insert: function(){
    this.$emit('insertItem', 123);
}
```

In the page containing the component:

```
<medialibrary @insertItem="insertItem(arg);"></medialibrary>


<script>
    function insertItem(arg){
        console.log('insertItem');
        console.log(arg);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In case the other component also is a Vue instance, you could use a [global event bus](https://www.google.com/search?q=vue+js+global+event+bus)

Comment: This is just one component (medialibrary) and I want to emit an event with a parameter to some Javascript which is in the HTML page outside of the VueJS instance.

Comment: Just call this global function from event intermediate event listener.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually more possible than it seems at first look. If the function is global (in particular, visible to the parent Vue), it can be called by the Vue even if it is not a method of the Vue. (It would arguably be a better idea to create a method that calls the global function.)

The main difficulty with your code was camelCasing where it should be kebab-case.

If you want `insertItem` to get the `arg` from the `$emit`, the HTML should only give the function name, and Vue will take care of passing the args:

```
<medialibrary id="app" @insert-item="insertItem"></medialibrary>
```

My snippet uses your original code, which provides arg from the parent Vue.

```js
function insertItem(arg) {
  console.log('insertItem');
  console.log(arg);
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    arg: 'hi there'
  },
  components: {
    medialibrary: {
      template: '<div><button @click="insert">Insert</button></div>',
      methods: {
        insert() {
          console.log("Emit");
          this.$emit('insert-item', 123);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<medialibrary id="app" @insert-item="insertItem(arg);"></medialibrary>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, know it would be something silly like the prop name :)